# Put javascript data into a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following javascript code:

```
game.bind('gameover', function(seconds) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var rank = game.getRank(seconds);
      scorecard.find('.time').text(seconds + ' sec');
      scorecard.find('.rank').text(rank[0]);
      scorecard.find('.byline').text(rank[1]);
      ...more code
```

In the following div this data is displayed (so the js script is working):

```
<div class="inner">
  <h3>Nice job! Your time:</h3>
  <h1 class="wobble time"><!-- 15 seconds --></h1>
  <h2 class="rank"><!-- Friendly Mallard --></h2>
  <h3 class="byline"><!-- (That's pretty good) --></h3>
</div>
```

Now I want to put the results also in a form so I can post it to the a database (mysql). So I've added a form and put it in the same div:

```
<form id="form" action="updatescore.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="time" name="time" value="" />
  <input type="text" id="rank" name="rank" value="" />
  <input type="text" id="byline" name="byline" value="" />
</form>
```

Now in the JS I've copied the lines (e.g. `scorecard.find('.time').text(seconds + ' sec');`) and changed it to look for the id, so `.` becomes `#` and passed it in the js like:

```
scorecard.find('.time').text(seconds + ' sec');
scorecard.find('#time').text(seconds + ' sec');
etc
```

So this should work I think, but the form inputs stay empty. What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards,

Maurice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `val()` instead of `text()` for setting the values

Comment: Thanks I'll try this if the solution from Fresheyeball doesn't work

Comment: This worked. Though the other solution also works, I still need a form since I also have php data to process

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking to move js variables into your database via `updatescore.php` you don't need to use a form at all! You can do it with AJAX.

```
  var scoreData = {
       time : time,
       rank : rank[0],
       byline : rank[1]
  };
  $.post('updatescore.php', scoreData); //done!
```